# EL1008E: Property or field 'description' cannot be found on object of type 'com.tgriff.exptracker.entity.Expense' - maybe not public or not valid?

Tags: spring-boot

I have been stuck with this error for a while every time I try to run my Spring Boot application:

org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'description' cannot be found on object of type 'com.tgriff.exptracker.entity.Expense' - maybe not public or not valid?

Here is my code:

Expense Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "expensetracker")
public class Expense {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "expense_category", nullable = true)
    private String category;

    //TODO: Why does private not work when displaying view? 
    @Column(name = "expense_description", nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "expense_cost", nullable = false)
    private double dollarAmount;

    //dynamic constructor to create objects dynimically
    public Expense(){

    }

    public Expense(String category, String description, double dollarAmount) {
        super();
        this.category = category;
        this.description = description;
        this.dollarAmount = dollarAmount;
    }
    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }
    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
    public String getDesciption() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public double getDollarAmount() {
        return dollarAmount;
    }
    public void setDollarAamount(double dollarAmount) {
        this.dollarAmount = dollarAmount;
    }

    
}
```

ExpenseController:

```
@Controller
public class ExpenseController {
    
    private ExpenseService expenseService;

    public ExpenseController(ExpenseService expenseService) {
        super();
        this.expenseService = expenseService;
    }

    //handler method to handle list students and return model and view
    @GetMapping("/expenses")
    public String listExpenses(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("expenses", expenseService.getAllExpenses());
        return "expenses";
    }

    
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class ExpenseServiceImpl implements ExpenseService {

    private ExpenseRepository expenseRepository;

    

    public ExpenseServiceImpl(ExpenseRepository expenseRepository) {
        super();
        this.expenseRepository = expenseRepository;
    }


    // List all expenses
    @Override
    public List<Expense> getAllExpenses() {
        
        return expenseRepository.findAll();
    }
    
}
```

expenses.html:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h1>List Expenses</h1>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead class="table-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th>Expense Category</th>
                    <th>Expense Description</th>
                    <th>Expense Cost</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr th:each = "expense: ${expenses}">
                    <td th:text = "${expense.category}"></td>
                    <td th:text = "${expense.description}"></td>
                    <td th:text = "${expense.dollarAmount}"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

It only happens for the description attribute of an Expense object but when I change the access modifier from private to public in the Expense class, the application works fine. Also, even though I was getting an error and the view was not displaying, it would still insert a record into my database in the description field.